# Publish my Istanbul index.html coverage file

Tags: reactjs, cypress, istanbul

I am generating a Istanbul coverage report for my React app.  The report is stored as an html file on my computer at `web/coverage/lcov-report/index.html`.  I want to share this report with my team.  I have tried uploading the `.html` file along with the generated `prettify.css` and `base.css` files to a Google Drive file, but my teammates aren't able to view the styled report, only the code.

Has anyone found a way to share a coverage report like this with their team?

Answer (score 0):

You could use nodeJS and puppeteer to generate a pdf report linking your html and css